# Changing FrontEnd automatic scrolling in version 8

Tags: front-end, customization, cells, printing

In *Mathematica* versions < 8, the FrontEnd has a very intelligent behavior:

- On evaluation, it by default automatically scrolls down the Notebook window to the last printed Output cell but also allows a user to scroll the Notebook window up by hand and then does not scroll down the window again automatically.
- If the user wishes to restore automatic scrolling it is sufficient to scroll down the window to the last currently printed Output cell and automatic scrolling will be restored.

I feel such behavior very comfortable. But in *Mathematica* 8 we have no such behavior by default. I found that it may be partially restored by setting

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 EvaluationCompletionAction -> {"ScrollToOutput"}]
```

But then it is not possible to stop automatic scrolling by scrolling the window by hands. It is possible to restore the old scrolling behavior?

---

Through *Mathematica* 10.4 the old scrolling behavior has not been restored.

- Have any new options come on line to control this?
- Is there a hook to determine scroll position that might be used for a workaround?
- Could [`PrintTemporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintTemporary.html) and/or [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) (which is active only when visible) be used to simulate the old behavior?
- If the old behavior is simply not achievable what is the best alternative for a similar workflow?

Comment: Welcome, Alexey!

Comment: Actually, I found the old behaviour rather annoying. Quite distracting when you were editing and running evaluations at the same time.

Comment: @Sjoerd With the old behavior we could not only edit the input during evaluation (as we can by default now) but also inspect already printed outputs from the running evaluation (by scrolling the page). And all of this without loosing automatic scrolling when we wish! I see no advantages in loosing this.

Comment: Well, it happened to me quite a lot that I got drawn to the bottom of the print area at times I didn't want to be there and when I succeeded staying above the scroll area it wasn't very stable either.

Comment: @Sjoerd I agree that editing during evaluation was not always stable (of course, it does not mean that this is bad idea itself). The main advantage of the old behavior is the ability to switch between inspecting of already printed outputs and automatic scrolling.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov It is unclear, do you mean: _"In Mathematica versions < 8..."_?

Comment: @shrx I mean at least *Mathematica* versions 5, 6 and 7 (I worked with).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ok :) good luck.

Comment: Alexey, I added a new section to this question probing for alternatives and workarounds, and noting that the behavior has not been restored through 10.1 and is presumably not going to be.  I hope you approve.

Comment: In March 2015 I send a suggestion to WRI tech support (CASE:2679254) with a link to this thread. They replied that it was forwarded to "the appropriate people in our development group", so I think we at least have a hope. I have nothing against the new section in my question.

Comment: In version 10.0 I have that, by default, the front end always auto-scrolls to view new output, regardless of previous hand scrolls by the user.  I take it from this question that I may disable *all* auto-scrolling by setting EvaluationCompletionAction to something else.  Is that correct?  Are there any other options as of version 10?

Comment: In Mathematica 10, it does not seem possible to peacefully write some code while it is evaluating. It keeps jumping back and forth between the code line I am writing and the end of the input part of the section that is being evaluated. Is there a way to normally work on the code while Mathematica 10 is evaluating part of the notebook?

Comment: @Wizzerad I suggest you to ask the tech support about it because (as you see) no one here seems to know how to get tiny control on the FrontEnd behavior while evaluating. If you get a solution, please post it here - it will help others.

Comment: @Wizzerad In *Mathematica* version 12.0 your problem seems to be [resolved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207042/280).