# Automatically scroll along with currently evaluating cell?

Tags: front-end, evaluation

If I'm evaluating an entire large notebook, I usually just press Alt-V Y to find the currently evaluating cell. Is there a way to keep the currently evaluating cell automatically in focus so that the notebook automatically scrolls there without me having to press any keys?

Comment: Related but distinct: [(1948)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1948/121), [(29396)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29396/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just tried this, and it seems to work. See if it works for you.

Type this in first cell (thanks to Kuba suggestion, changed it to use `SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[]`)

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellProlog :> SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell]]
```

You can make the above an initialization cell.

Then `Evaluation->Evaluate` notebook. now it will scroll down, keeping current evaluating cell in view all the time.

[image]

reference: [how-to-make-cursor-jump-automatically-to-next-input-cell-after-evaluating-previo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29396/how-to-make-cursor-jump-automatically-to-next-input-cell-after-evaluating-previo)

Comment: @Kuba thanks, You suggestion of using `EvaluationCell[]` is better. I updated it.

Comment: Perfect! And elegant!

Answer (score 8):

This is not as general as Nasser's answer but in case of output being there you can use:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ScrollToOutput"]
```