# "Find currently evaluating cell" does not seem to work correctly

Tags: front-end

In the drop-down menu Evaluation Mathematica has the nice-sounding item "Find Currently Evaluating Cell" (Alt+V Y). In several versions of Mathematica (currently using 11.0) I have noticed that this item does not seem to work properly: when the evaluation queue contains several items it always seems to select the one that is the closest to the start of the notebook, even when the cells were evaluated in another order.

A minimal example to see this is to evaluate `Pause[20]` twice, starting with the second cell.

**My question** is if this (bug?) is known, and if there a way to fix it?

(I am aware of [this question and its answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76822/29926), which are related but different.)

*Background:* A situation in which this could occur is the following. Let's say I have a big notebook of which I want to evaluate several cells of which I know the computation time will be quite long. I can try to let Mathematica evaluate these cells overnight, say. In such a case I might want to start by evaluating the cells that I expect to take the least amount of time, followed by others that I expect to take longer and longer. In the morning I want to see how far Mathematica got but "Find Currently Evaluating Cell" does not work. (In that case I could also use the answers given at the above-mentioned question to find this out, but that's not quite the same as what I'm asking for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: create a dynamic object `Dynamic@evaluatedCell` and start each of the following cells with an expression `evaluatedCell=EvaluationCell[]`. Your `evaluatedCell` will be a clickable object, which will scroll your notebook to the cell currently evaluated. Your dynamic object is going to be updated every time a cell changed, so you always know the cell actually evaluating.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I forgot to accept your workaround before! Thanks