# Scroll To Bottom Of Output Automatically

Tags: output

Is there a way to get Mathematica to automatically scroll to the bottom of output similar to a terminal on cell evaluation?

Doing a quick search for output in Ctrl+Shift+O I get the following options.

```
ScrollUndo, CellHorizontalScrolling, Scrollbars
```

Comment: like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76822/5478?

Comment: @Kuba the 2nd answer seems to work in M10 for this answer.  I believe the 1st answer works but for a different question.  Either that or it doesn't work at all.  So to recap the 2nd answer to the 1st question solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This I don't believe is a duplicate of the question Kuba linked but the 2nd answer to that question seems to solve the issue.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ScrollToOutput"]
```